# How to change the color of the highlighted cell in Excel

Tags: excel

Not sure if this is a possibility but I figured if anyone would know it would be you guys.

Basically just wondering if there is a way to change the color of the cell that is highlighted or selected.

I frequently have to Ctrl+F through a lot of data and it would be so awesome if the highlighted cell didn't just have the bolded border around it but maybe had a different color.

Even more ideal would be if it highlighted the row and column to zero in on the cell but that's probably asking too much. A man can dream can't he?

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Ctrl+1 and add a fill

Comment: More like I have a worksheet, I ctrl+f something, and then the border around the found cell is bright green or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the colour of the gridlines (it's in Options -> Advanced) to a much lighter gray, this makes the highlighted cell stand out a lot more

Answer (score 0):

Right Click -> Format Cells -> Fill -> Choose Color -> click OK